# Why do I see multiple spark installations directories?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a ubuntu server which has `spark` installed in it.

I don't have sudo access to this server.

So under my directory, I created a new `virtual environment` where I installed `pyspark`

When I type the below command

```
whereis spark-shell   #see below


/opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell2.cmd /opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell.cmd /opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell /home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/spark-shell2.cmd /home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/spark-shell.cmd /home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/spark-shell
```

**another command**

```
echo 'sc.getConf.get("spark.home")' | spark-shell

scala> sc.getConf.get("spark.home")
res0: String = /home/abcd/.pyenv/versions/bio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark
```

q1) Am I using the right commands to find the installation directory of spark?

q2) Can help me understand why do I see `3 opt paths` and `3 pyenv paths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spark installation (like the one you have in `/opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7`) typically comes with a pyspark installation within it. You can check this by downloading and extracting this tarball (https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.6/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz).

If you install `pyspark` in a virtual environment, you're installing another instance of `pyspark` which comes without the Scala source code but comes with compiled spark code as jars (see the `jars` folder in your pyspark installation). `pyspark` is a wrapper over spark (which is written in Scala). This is probably what you're seeing in `/home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/`.

The scripts `spark-shell2.cmd` and `spark-shell.cmd` in the same directory are part of the same spark installation. These are text files and you can `cat` them. You will see that `spark-shell.cmd` calls `spark-shell2.cmd` within it. You will probably have a lot more scripts in your `/opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/` folder, all of which are a part of the same spark installation. Same goes for the folder `/home/abcd/.pyenv/shims/`. Finally, `/home/abcd/.pyenv/versions/bio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark` seems like yet another `pyspark` installation.

It shouldn't matter which `pyspark` installation you use. In order to use spark, a java process needs to be created that running the Scala/Java code (from the jars in your installation).

Typically, when you run a command like this

```py
# Python code
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('myappname').getOrCreate()
```

then you create a new java process that's runs spark.

If you run the script `/opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark` then you also create a new java process.

You can check if there is indeed such a java process running using something like this: `ps aux | grep "java"`.

Comment: one quick question. When I have installed spark in `/opt/` directory, why does my first command output also shows up the virtual environment `spark-shell2.cmd`, `spark-shell.cmd`, `spark-shell2`?

Comment: Yes, I did install `pyspark` in virtual environment, but shouldn't I be seeing only this `/home/abcd/.pyenv/versions/bio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark`? but why `spark-sheel.cmd2` etc

Comment: What's the difference between 1st and 2nd command? Why 2nd command gives only `pyspark` installation path? Can help me please?

Comment: `whereis spark-shell` is simply searching your disk for all files that match the pattern `spark-shell`. This is no different than searching for a file/folder name, say, `music-folder`. `sc.getConf.get("spark.home")` shows the particular spark installation used to create the spark session in your python program.

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have another related post. If you have time, will you be able to help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883142/how-to-find-spark-installation-details